# make pendrive bootable via command line Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-10.04, iso-image, shell-script

I'm trying to burn a .iso image of Ubuntu into a pendrive using command line in Ubuntu but I'm having serious problems.

I'm looking for a tool, which I can invoke from a shell script, something like USB-creator-gtk (which is a GUI and works perfectly but I can't use it from a console cause it has to be automatic without user interaction).

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'll really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If the ISO is of a bootable image just use dd.

The command is quite powerful and simple. Say you have a ISO of Ubuntu called ubuntu.iso, and the USB drive is /dev/sda.

The command would be `dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sda`

This will block copy the ISO image onto the drive. By default I believe the block side is 512k, which you can modify by adding `bs='blockside'`

For more info look at `man dd`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. DD works for copy the structure but it doesn't make the pendrive bootable!! any ideas for that? in fact i've tested DD but without success making the Pendrive bootable

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks for the replies! at the end we solved the problem doing this:
*Convert the .iso file into .img file usign "usb-creator-gtk"
*Then with a .img of course DD works perfect!

Thanks again, Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

Unbuntu already has a tool for do that, its name is "start up disk creator" or in spanish "creador de discos de arranque", it's very easy to use, try it ;)

Comment: When I select the iso in start up disk creator it doesnt display in the list, and the button is disabled to make... :(